# Is there a quick way of finding an Euler Circuit from an undirected adjacency list?

Tags: java, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

For testing purposes, I'm using the following adjacency matrix:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A   0   1   1   0   0   0  
B   1   0   1   1   1   0  
C   1   1   0   1   1   0  
D   0   1   1   0   1   1  
E   0   1   1   1   0   1  
F   0   0   0   1   1   0
```

And from this, I can get the following adjacency list:

```
A:  B   C 
B:  A   C   D   E 
C:  A   B   D   E 
D:  B   C   E   F 
E:  B   C   D   F 
F:  D   E
```

Is there a quick method of finding an Euler Circuit from this list? And if so, is it correct to assume that I would then be able to use said method to find possible Euler Circuits in any subsets of the list?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think I may have found a method, will take a bit to code

Comment: What do you mean with *subset*? You can easily verify that there is an Eulerian circuit: the degree of every vertex is even (given the graph is undirected)...

Comment: Can you confirm a possible answer? Would: String[] path = {"BA", "AC", "CB", "BD", "DE", "EF", "FD", "DC", "CE", "EB"} work? (index is the path#)

Comment: See [this page](http://www.graph-magics.com/articles/euler.php).

Comment: Oh yeah what CommuSoft said is a cleaner version of the algorithm I set up, and I'm not even sure if mine is right. Use it!

Comment: @CommuSoft I think this definition is not sufficient. The graph also needs to be a single connected component, otherwise you could have, let's imagine, a graph with two connected components that are C3 graphs (so every vertex has even degree - 2 in this case), but there is no Eulerian cycle possible.

Comment: For clarification, by subset, I mean if there is no Eulerian Circuit, then let's remove a vertex (probably one with an odd degree) and then attempt to find a Eulerian Circuit with the remaining vertices.

Comment: @RileyCarney Yes, I just checked and that is a possible answer. Did you get that from the adjacency list?

Comment: Yeah, my algorithm is incredibly messy compared to the website answer that CommuSoft posted however, I'm pretty sure I put like 3 extra steps that make no sense. Not sure how it'd do for testing tables that don't have a possible Eulerian Circuit since only did with his.

Answer (score 1):

To know if there exists an Eulerian path in an undirected graph, two conditions must be met:

- all the vertices with non-zero degree belong to a single connected component
- the degree of each vertex must be even

So for instance the following graph

[image]

does not admit an eulerian circuit since there is no way to reach the edges of the right subgraph from the left subgraph and vice-versa.

You can check if a graph is a single connected component in linear time (with respect to the number of edges and vertices of the graph) using a DFS or a BFS approach. Start from any vertex with non-zero degree, and check if you can reach any other vertex of the graph (except the ones with zero degree but you can't reach them by definition anyway).

When it's done, check that the degree of each vertex is even.

At that point you know than an Eulerian circuit must exist. To find one, you can use Fleury's algorithm (there are many examples on the web, for instance [here](https://www.austincc.edu/powens/+Topics/HTML/05-6/05-6.html)).

The time complexity of the Fleury's algorithm is O(|E|) where E denotes the set of edges. But you also need to detect bridges when running the algorithm. You can detect bridges with Tarjan's Algorithm which has a time complexity of O(|V|+|E|).

So the overall time complexity for Fleury's algorithm is O(|E|<sup>2</sup>)

---

So from the graph induced by your adjacent list:

[image]

1. Starts from A (arbitrary)
2. Travel from A to B (arbitrary)
3. Travel from B to C (arbitrary)
4. Now you must travel to D because the edge A-C is a bridge edge
5. Travel from D to B (arbitrary)
6. Travel from B to E (you don't have the choice)
7. Travel from E to F (you can't go to C since E-C is a bridge edge)

Now you don't have the choice so

8. Travel from F to D
9. Travel from D to E
10. Travel from E to C
11. Travel from C to A

So an Eulerian circuit is A-B-C-D-B-E-F-D-E-C-A.